# How to create an example extension for Hybris 2011 version

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I just download the latest 2011.1, and try to use "ant extgen" command to create a default extennsion, but meet following error:

Would anyone know how to deal with it?

```
extgen.xml:293: The following error occurred while executing this line:
extgen.xml:35: Source directory '${ext.develop.path}' for template 'training' does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run it again and it should work the second time.

There does seem to be a bug in the build scripts that has probably been there a while. I assume that `ant extgen` was the first thing you ran after unpacking. There is no `config` folder so the build script did this:

```
[input]  No config folder was found at /path/to/hybris/config.
[input]  Please choose the configuration template.
[input]  Press [Enter] to use the default value ([develop], production)
```

and you chose `develop`

Unfortunately it stores your choice in a variable `input.template` which is the same name as used when later on the script asks you what extension template you want to base yours on. So the script sees that the variable already has a value and doesn't ask you:

```
[input] Please choose a template for generation.
[input] Press [Enter] to use the default value (commercewebservices, commercewebservicestests, yacceleratorfulfilmentprocess, yacceleratormarketplaceintegration, yacceleratorordermanagement, yacceleratorstorefront, yaddon, ybackoffice, ycommercewebservices, ycommercewebservicestest, ydocumentcart, [yempty], yhacext, yocc, yoccaddon, yocctests, ysapproductconfigaddon, ysmarteditmodule, yvoid, ywebservices)
```

It then tries to find a template extension `develop` and fails.

Running it the second time means your config folder is already generated and it correctly asks you which extension you want to base your extension on.